# The container is 2 pixels bigger (counting the border) than its buttons even though everything is border-box

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to find out why when I try to zoom in, the button container's width and height are sometimes less than the distance between top to bottom border and left to right border for more than an hour and I am going crazy.

Summarize the problem

- I want the blue and gray background to take up the entire area inside the border responsively.
- What happened was that the width and height of the button container look like they were moved up by a small number of pixels and moved right by a small number of pixels.
- The container is 2 pixels bigger (counting the border) than its buttons.

Describe what you've tried

- I tried googling it, looking on Stack Overflow and Reddit but I couldn't find an answer. Maybe I don't know how to google...
- I tried changing btn-container to flexbox instead of grid, that didn't work.
- I tried messing around with overflow but that was fruitless.
- I tried messing around with btn-container__left and btn-container__right buttons' position to see if there was any effect but no.
- I tried increasing or decreasing width and height to mess with it and see if there was any effect, but no effect, unfortunately.

Picture 1 - Zoom at 150%
[image: button container zoomed at 150%]

Picture 2 - Zoom at 150% - Highlighted
[image: button container zoomed at 150% - Highlighted]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* TODO: Why is btn-container's width and height less than content + border width and height even thought it is border-box??? */

.btn-container {
  width: 24rem;
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 25%, 1);

  overflow: hidden;

  position: fixed;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.btn-container__left {
  background: none;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;

  position: relative;
}

.btn-container__right {
  background: none;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;

  position: relative;
}



.btn-container__left::before {
  content: "";

  width: 110%;
  height: 100%;

  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 65%, 1);

  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -10%;
  z-index: -1;

  transform: skewX(-30deg);

}

.btn-container__right::before {  
  content: "";

  width: 110%;
  height: 100%;

  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 65%, 1);

  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;

  transform: skewX(-30deg);
}



.btn-container__left--selected::before {
  background-color: hsla(190, 100%, 45%, 1);
}

.btn-container__right--selected::before {
  background-color: hsla(190, 100%, 50%, 1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button class="btn-container__left btn-container__left--selected">Fixed Offset</button>
    <button class="btn-container__right"> Linear Drift</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because 100% of 1px is 1px, but 150% of 1px is 1.5px, there's no such thing as half a pixel, thus, your browser rounds it, creating that offset at 150%.

You can opt to use a background in your container to cover up any areas left transparent, because of the rounding.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* TODO: Why is btn-container's width and height less than content + border width and height even thought it is border-box??? */

.btn-container {
  width: 24rem;
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 25%, 1);
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 25%, 1);

  overflow: hidden;

  position: fixed;
  top: 50vh;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
}

.btn-container__left {
  background: none;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;

  position: relative;
}

.btn-container__right {
  background: none;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;

  position: relative;
}



.btn-container__left::before {
  content: "";

  width: 110%;
  height: 100%;

  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 65%, 1);

  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -10%;
  z-index: -1;

  transform: skewX(-30deg);

}

.btn-container__right::before {  
  content: "";

  width: 110%;
  height: 100%;

  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 65%, 1);

  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;

  transform: skewX(-30deg);
}



.btn-container__left--selected::before {
  background-color: hsla(190, 100%, 45%, 1);
}

.btn-container__right--selected::before {
  background-color: hsla(190, 100%, 50%, 1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button class="btn-container__left btn-container__left--selected">Fixed Offset</button>
    <button class="btn-container__right"> Linear Drift</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```